# Why I can't read subdir with my recursive code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

[This error showed up when i run my recursive to read all subdir i dont know how to solve this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcYTH.png)

THis is my recursive code

```
    private void recursiveSubDir(dynamic workingdirectories)
    {

        var targetDir = workingdirectories;
        foreach (string _selectedDir in targetDir)
        {

            var targetFile = Directory.GetFiles(_selectedDir);
            foreach (var selectedFile in targetFile)
            {
                string enc_selectedFile = GetMD5FromFile(selectedFile);
                string[] md5text = File.ReadAllLines("md5 encryptor.txt");
                foreach (string md5textcheck in md5text)
                {
                    if (enc_selectedFile.Contains(md5textcheck))
                    {
                        virus = virus + 1;
                    }
                }

            }
            MessageBox.Show(_selectedDir);
            recursiveSubDir(_selectedDir);
        }
    }
```

and this i call the recursive

```
try{ string[] md5text = File.ReadAllLines("md5 encryptor.txt");
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(lokdirek);
                var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(lokdirek, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(d => !isexcluded(_excludeDirectories, d));

                int directoryCount = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(lokdirek).Length;
                recursiveSubDir(dirs); }
```

Comment: Questions that depend on external resources become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed.

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `_selectedDir` when the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

check the type of workingdirectories. The actual code (the one you send the picture from) is a little different than the one you posted. In the picture there is this:

```
foreach (var _selectedDir in targetDir)
```

So there is var instead string, and then we have no certainty that the _selectedDir is actually a string. It can contain, for example, objects, which will create similar error. If you fix that so that the above line is similar to the one you posted and you get InvalidCastException at runtime then I am pretty sure that is the issue.